# Is there a way to send a text message via voice command in iOS after dictating it?

Tags: ios, messages, voice-dictation

I know that there are voice commands for inserting a new line or inserting punctuation, but I was wondering if there's a voice command to send a text message once it has been dictated. I tried saying the word "send," but that didn't seem to work. Is this possible?

P. S. This question was written using the voice dictation feature! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have asked Siri to Send a new Message to some person, Siri Normally asks " Do you want me to send it" when it thinks you have finished.
Saying "Send" normally works. And Siri will say "Ok then I will send the Text message.."

I do not think there is a way to do it after you have used dictation.

Apples dictations [command list](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203084)

Comment: Ok, so this only works when using the Siri interface, but not in the messages app itself?

Comment: as far as i know. I have tried my self. And have not got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enhanced dictation enabled (OS X Mavericks 10.9 or later) you can run commands such as saying "Press Return Key" after dictating your message and the return key will be pressed and thus your message will be sent.

Comment: Can you clarify this? Is there a setting we can turn on to enable this? It doesn’t work

Answer (score -2):

There is no enhanced dictation feature on the iPhone